# Prometheus Starlette Exporter Get average request duration

Tags: prometheus, fastapi, promql, starlette

I try to calculate an in my opinion pretty basic metric: the average request duration of succesful requests.

I used the following promQL query

`floor(increase(starlette_request_duration_seconds_sum{path="/", status !~ "2.."}[10m])) / floor(increase(starlette_request_duration_seconds_count{path="/", status !~ "2.."}[10m]))`

I found out two things:

1. `increase(starlette_request_duration_seconds_sum{path="/", status !~ "2.."}[10m])` doubles my request time and hence the whole metric is useless.
2. I need floor because without floor it would also give me only nearly the results (e.g. I send 3 requests it would ouput 3.3)

Is there a common practice how to really get the results

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus extrapolates [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) results - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746). That's why you get unexpected fractional results when trying to calculate increase over integer [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter). If you need expected integer results from `increase()` function, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). This is Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on, and it returns the expected integer results from `increase()` function over slowly changing integer counters.